# PHP Week number

Tags: php, week-number

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
$now = strtotime('now'); // 1388430373
$weekNumber = date('W', $now);
var_dump($weekNumber);
```

Why this code shows `01`?
It's now 30th december 2013

How to get `right` week number?

Comment: @Rottingham `D`? OP is searching for a week number, not a day.

Comment: Sorry ready wrong, thought he was looking for the day in the week

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This week **is** the first week of the new year. That is the right week number.

PS: Last week was #52: `echo date('W', strtotime('-1 week'));` Output: `52`. A year only has 52 weeks so...

Comment: I can't wait to see how many more of these we see until Thursday, cause this is #3 for today so far that I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

ISO 8601 week number is based on WEEK 01 which is

- the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the formal ISO
  definition)

which is

- the week with 4 January in it,
- the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year,
- the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January.

where a week is defined as beginning with Monday and ending with Sunday

**EDIT**

Depending on your definition of week number, you might consider

```
$weekNumber = floor(date('z', $now) / 7) + 1;
```

which will give the number of 7-day periods since 1st January, but it will vary from year to year which day of the week is the week start day